# Set preview.app to default to "content only" view

Tags: macos, preview, defaults

Is there any way to make (Mountain Lion) Preview's default view 'content only'?

Comment: Hmm - all items I click from Finder open in content only view. Have you tried setting that for one or two items and then quitting the app?

Comment: Interesting.  Yeah, that's basically the first thing I do for every document I open... it hasn't taken.  Even re-opening the same document.

Comment: If you make a new user account, I would presume it matches the intended behavior. If so, you could delete your preferences for that app and hopefully restore the default behavior.

Comment: So you think my preferences got corrupted/broken somehow?  'Delete the preferences' means delete the appropriate plist file right?  Do you know which one / where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for something that would seem to be the opposite of what you wanted (i.e. to have all PDFs open and show the "Thumbnails" of each page, as is an option in the "View" menu.

As such, I found, on the Apple Support community the following:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4582012

It would seem you have to go to Preferences> PDF> un-tick the "Always Show Sidebar" option beside "Opening for the first time" option.

Hope that helps a bit! (?)

Comment: Thank you!  Finally: relief from my suffering.  Can't believe I missed that tick-box...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for previewing .doc files. Is this a bug, or does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: There's no "Always show sidebar" option for images i.e. jpegs